# Readthedocs: how to ignore requirements file?

Tags: python, travis-ci, read-the-docs

I have a project (recently joined) that depends on basemap when running certain tests. Specifying "basemap" in the setup.py alone results in the following on Travis CI:

```
Collecting basemap (from mypkg==1.1.6)
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement basemap (from mypkg==1.1.6)
  No distributions at all found for basemap (from mypkg==1.1.6)
```

To get around this the previous maintainers started a requirements.txt file with:

```
git+https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.git
```

Which we install in our travis yaml with:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then the rest of our Travis install works. Now when Readthedocs tries to build documentation it automatically grabs the requirements file (even though it says the default is `None`), but fails when it can't find libgeos. To work around this I created a `readthedocs.yml` file and tried:

```
requirements_file:
```

Which caused Rtd to hang on "Cloning..." so I tried:

```
requirements_file: ''
```

Which also hangs. My final working solution was to create an empty file in "docs/requirements.txt" and specify that for Rtd.

Does anyone have a better way of solving this? Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Thinking about it, I guess the better question is why does Travis not know how to install basemap?

Comment: `pip install basemap` doesn't work for me. Why do you expect it to? Also what if you just had a `python_requirements.txt` so that it's not automatically detected by Readthedocs and told travis to explicitly `pip install -r python_requirements.txt`?

Comment: Does this project add similar dependencies? https://github.com/GeographicaGS/daynight2geojson/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: @AlexHall I guess I just assumed that a widely used library would be easily installable, but now that you say that I think the only reason I didn't get an error when I did `pip install basemap` was because it was already installed.
@OwenGriffiths I found that repository shortly after posting this question. I think that will be my solution as it seems the most obvious way to install everything. After researching why basemap needs an external host it makes sense (it's too large for PyPI) that extra steps need to be taken.

Comment: @OwenGriffiths I tried to implement what they did on that repository and got an error from travis. Also it looks like the `--allow-external` and `--allow-unverified` are deprecated in newer versions of pip so that solution won't work forever. I think installing basemap from source is the only accepted way.

Comment: @AlexHall I had the same problem and preferred to point readthedocs towards a fake requirements.txt. IMHO readthedocs should have an option where you can just tell it to not automatically install a requirements.txt. Renaming the true one breaks a few other naming conventions so that is not very satisfying either.